# Powershell Store Mysql Query "Select From" Output as a String Variable

Tags: mysql, powershell

I would like to use the data from a Mysql query within my Powershell script for later use.

Here is what i am using to query Mysql:

```
run-MySQLQuery -ConnectionString "$databaseConnection;" -Query "Select * From table where  source = 'projectname';";
```

The mysql query output is:

Source | Url | Count | RunTime | AvgRunTime | Country | Rank

I have tried adding a $variable = at the start but this outputs it as a system object and i cannot figure out how to use this if for example i wanted to just use the source for example google.co.uk from the query in a variable as string.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```powershell
$result = run-MySQLQuery -ConnectionString "$databaseConnection;" -Query "Select * From table where  source = 'projectname';";
$result.Source
```

You should be able to access all properties of your `$result` object using dot(.) notation. If you want to know what properties or methods are available on `$result` object use `get-member` cmdlet:

```powershell
$result | get-member
```